# Getting error "The publishableKey passed to Clerk is invalid."" in a NextJS application

Tags: next.js, clerk

While trying a AI gen stack using Next.js as app code and Clerk, Pinecode, the startup fails with this message. I have provided the correct keys values in the environment variables.

Comment: How did you fix this in the end?